# How to get Full Speed Run trophy in Braid

Tags: ps3, achievements, braid

I'm looking at getting the "Full Speed Run" trophy in Braid on PS3.  The description of the trophy is:

> Did some kind of speed run through the game.

So, two questions:

1. Do I have to get *all* the puzzle pieces, or can I just plow through the levels?
2. Do I have to beat the challenge time, or can I take as long as I need?

Comment: Not that hard anymore, there's been a lot of new tricks discivered lately. Here's my current personal best of 26:30: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ArX0jUMiz8 This is PC version btw, and not PS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the Speed Run trophy, you must beat the game in under 45 minutes. This means you *must* get all the puzzle pieces (because you can't complete the game otherwise).

As I've only played the PC version of the game, I'm not sure what you mean by challenge time.

Comment: I think the 45 mins is the challenge time.

Comment: Gosh! 45 minutes? It looks hard! :P

Comment: Just practice, practice, practice.  You'll get it eventually once you've memorized the solutions to the puzzles pretty well.